# CODE CONVERSION C# TO VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

can anyone help me to convert this c# code into vb?

i am facing problem whenever i run my project, can anyone help me resolve this issue? the code is working fine in c# but when i try this in vb it throws the error **PUBLIC EVENT SELECTEDVALUECHANGED IS AND EVENT AND CANNOT BE CALLED DIRECTLY, USE A 'RAISE EVENT' STATEMENT TO RAISE AN EVENT**. 
The problem is how to convert this C# syntax ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValueChanged -= ItemNameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged;
into vb syntax?

Here is the code;

```
 Private Sub ItemNameComboBox_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ItemNameComboBox.MouseClick
    LoadDataIntoItemComboBox()

    ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValueChanged -= ItemNameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged

    ItemNameComboBox.DisplayMember = "ItemName"
    ItemNameComboBox.ValueMember = "Unit_Price"

   ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValueChanged += ItemNameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged
End Sub

Private Sub ItemNameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValueChanged

    Dim ProductPrice As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValue)
    UnitPriceTextBox.Text = ProductPrice.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: In C# you use `+=` and `-=` to register and unregister event handlers.  In VB, you use `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`.

Comment: Thanks A lot it worked perfectly. jmcilhinney

Comment: You should always accept an answer when your issue is resolved.  If no one has provided an answer that resolved the issue, write one yourself and accept it.  That way, everyone knows that the issue is resolved and, if they're looking for help themselves, how it was done.  I didn't provide an answer myself because I didn't feel like writing the whole thing out.  You've already done that though, so it's just a copy and paste job.

Comment: yeah you are right mate. Actually i am new to this forum and don't know much about it. thanks again for another good piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the issue and would like to share the solution just in case anyone else experiences the same problem.
well in C# we use to write -= to disable an event and += to enable an event, e.g. 
this code will disable the event

```
ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValueChanged -= ItemNameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged;
```

and this code will enable the event.

```
ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValueChanged -= ItemNameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged;
```

NOW CONVERTING THESE LINE OF CODES FROM C# TO VB.NET
In vb we use AddHandler instead of += to enable or register an event and similarly RemoveHandler instead of -= to disable or unregister an event.
So the vb syntax for the above code to disable the event will be

```
RemoveHandler ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValueChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ItemNameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged)
```

and
to enable the event

```
AddHandler ItemNameComboBox.SelectedValueChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ItemNameComboBox_SelectedValueChanged)
```

hope i have answered the question.

Comment: You've added an answer, which is good, but you haven't accepted it.

Comment: I see.  I wasn't aware of that.